# How insert data in manyToOne relationship ? NestJs

Tags: javascript, orm, nestjs

I'm new with ORM system and I'm trying to insert a data "Mark" binded with an object "pseudo".

This my entities,
Pseudo:

```js
@Entity()
export class PseudoEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({unique: true})
    pseudo: string;

    @Column({ default: 1 })
    application_version: number;

    @Column({ default: -1 })
    score_on_last_calculation: number;

    @Column({default: 1})
    nb_request: number;

    @Column({default: -1})
    nb_mark_on_last_calculation: number;
    
    @OneToMany(type => Mark, marks => marks)
    marks: Mark[];
}
```

And Mark:

```js
@Entity()
export class MarkEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  int: number;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime'})
  submission_date: Date;

  @Column()
  mark: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Pseudo,
    pseudo => pseudo,
  )
  pseudo: Pseudo;
}
```

This is my service to insert the data:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MarkService {
  constructor(private pseudoService: PseudoService) {}

  async postMark(pseudo: string, mark: number) {
    await this.pseudoService.findPseudo(pseudo).then(
      p =>
         getConnection()
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .insert()
          .into(Mark)
          .values([
            {
              mark: mark,
              pseudo: p,
            },
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I succeed to insert a Pseudo but not a mark :/

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should make a few slight changes to your entities:

```js
@OneToMany(type => Mark, marks => marks.pseudo)
marks: Mark[];

@ManyToOne(
  type => Pseudo,
  pseudo => pseudo.marks,
)
pseudo: Pseudo;
```

Having made the changes above, use the injected `pseudoRepository` for querying and updating the desired `Pseudo`: (more about [Registering and Injecting entities](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database))

```
@Injectable()
export class MarkService {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(Pseudo) private readonly pseudoRepository: Repository<Pseudo>) { }

    async postMark(mark: number, pseudo: Pseudo): Promise<void> {
    
        let _mark = new Mark();

        mark.mark = mark;

        mark.pseudo = await pseudoRepository.findOne({ pseudo });

        await this.pseudoRepository.save(_mark)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) At the last code line, did you mean markRepository.save(mark) ?

Comment: Do I have to import something  in my module to use @InjectRepository ? Because I have this error. ```Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MarkService (?, MarkEntityRepository, PseudoService). Please make sure that the argument PseudoEntityRepository at index [0] is available in 
the PseudoModule context.```

Comment: Yes you do, read more about it in the link I've attached in my post

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but I suppose this should work:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PseudoEntity as Pseudo } from '../entity/pseudo.entity';
import { MarkEntity as Mark } from '../entity/mark.entity';
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class PseudoService {
 async postMark(markInput: number, pseudoInput: string) {
    let mark = new Mark();
    mark.mark = markInput;
    mark.submission_date = Date.now();
    mark.pseudo = await await repository.findOne({ pseudo: pseudoInput});
    await getConnection().manager
            .save(mark)
            .then(mark => {
                console.log("Mark has been saved. Mark id is ", mark.id);
            });
  }

  //....

}
```

You should probably add a check in case no pseudo is found within the database for this pseudoInput.